# Header layout in HTML document

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the following header layout in my HTML document which I visualised in Word:

[image]

Where the **logo** is at the **leftmost** edge of the header and a **h1** tag wording "Welcome to UI" which is at the **center** of the header.

Now, I have the following:

[image]

How do i get the h1 wording "Welcome to UI" to be inside the header and centered?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background: #dfdbd8c9;
    height: 10%;
}

.header_content img {
    height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>houseform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "header_content">
            <img src = "images/sun.png">
            <h1>Welcome to UI</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background: #dfdbd8c9;
    height: 10%;

}

.header_content img {
    height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>houseform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "header_content">
            <img src = "images/sun.png">
            <h1>Welcome to UI</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this can help**

```css
.header_content  {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  background:#ffaaaa;
}

.header_content h1{
  text-align:center;
}


.header_content img {
    height: 90px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>houseform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "header_content">
            <img src = "images/sun.png">
            <h1>Welcome to UI</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the h1 element to a div and used `display:flex`  to get the content in to same level.

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    header {
        background: #dfdbd8c9;
        height: 10%;
    }
    .header_content{
    display: flex;
    }
    
    .header_content .title{
      font-size:26px;
      margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
    }

    .header_content img {
        height: 90px;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>houseform</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class = "header_content">

<img src = "images/sun.png">
                <div class="title">Welcome to UI</div>

            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using CSS flex property.

```css
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .logo{
        height: 80px;
        max-width: 100px;
        flex-grow: 1;
        background: url(https://icon-library.net//images/google-chrom-icon/google-chrom-icon-5.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 60px;
    }
    .menu{
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <header>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h1>Welcome to UI</h1>
        </div>
 </header>
```